# Non www to www subfolders and inner pages are not redirecting

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am redirecting non www to www and I have added the below code in my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Also tried below code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The above code is working if I access my domain like example.com and redirecting to https://www.example.com

Now my issue is, when I am accessing my URLlike https://example.com/demo or https://example/gift/abcd/xyz then it's not redirecting to www domain and I am getting error 404 not found

Would you help me out with this issue?

Full .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WP Rocket v3.14.4.2
# END WP Rocket

Options -Indexes

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress example.com is for reference
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.in [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]


<IfModule mod_substitute.c>
SubstituteMaxLineLength 10M
</IfModule>
# BEGIN DS-XML-RPC-API
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN DS-XML-RPC-API" and "END DS-XML-RPC-API" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<Files xmlrpc.php>
order deny,allow
deny from all

</Files>

# END DS-XML-RPC-API


# Admin account username disclosure

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} author=\d
RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R=301]

# Wordfence WAF
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value auto_prepend_file '/var/www/html/wordfence-waf.php'
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
    php_value auto_prepend_file '/var/www/html/wordfence-waf.php'
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php.c>
    php_value auto_prepend_file '/var/www/html/wordfence-waf.php'
</IfModule>
<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>
</Files>






# END Wordfence WAF

# BEGIN ShortPixel Adaptive Images
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN ShortPixel Adaptive Images" and "END ShortPixel Adaptive Images" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.

# END ShortPixel Adaptive Images

ServerSignature Off



# BEGIN Headers Security Advanced & HSTS WP 5.0.28
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization"
Header set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
Header set Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy "unsafe-none; report-to='default'"
Header set Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy-Report-Only "unsafe-none; report-to='default'"
Header set Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy "unsafe-none"
Header set Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy-Report-Only "unsafe-none; report-to='default'"
Header set Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy "cross-origin"
Header set Permissions-Policy "accelerometer=(), autoplay=(), camera=(), cross-origin-isolated=(), display-capture=(self), encrypted-media=(), fullscreen=*, geolocation=(self), gyroscope=(), keyboard-map=(), magnetometer=(), microphone=(), midi=(), payment=*, picture-in-picture=(), publickey-credentials-get=(), screen-wake-lock=(), sync-xhr=(), usb=(), xr-spatial-tracking=(), gamepad=(), serial=()"
Header set Referrer-Policy "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000"
Header set X-Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; img-src *; media-src * data:;"
Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header set X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies "none"
</IfModule>
# END Headers Security Advanced & HSTS WP
```

[image]

Second image and it's working

[image]

Comment: Both versions should work fine, I can't see anything wrong with them, and https://htaccess.madewithlove.com (while not the best tool for more complex cases), agrees. Do you have any other rules that might interfere?

Comment: @CBroe,  No I haven't set any more rules in this

Comment: Then how is a URL like `/gift/abcd/xyz` working on your site? You mentioned that as one of the examples that was not working any more _now_, so it must have done before, yes? But that is not really pointing to an actually existing file named `xyz` in a folder `/gift/abcd`, is it? If not, then there presumably must be something more involved, than just what you have shown us so far.

Comment: @CBroe, example.com is the email domain that works on wordpress. if I use  https://example.com/gift/abcd/xyz then it's saying 404 error not found but I have use https://www.example.com/gift/abcd/xyz then it's working

Comment: _"example.com is the email domain that works on wordpress"_ - not sure what that is even supposed to mean. What's email got to do with any of this? _"works on wordpress"_ - are you trying to say, that you are using wordpress.com to host your blog, and have a custom domain added to it via that your content can be accessed ...?

Comment: @CBroe, Sorry, Typeo mistake, it's not email it's the main..

Comment: Then there must be more to the URL rewriting setup, otherwise your WP site would hardly be able to use "pretty URLs" in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe, I have added a full htaccess file in the question..

Comment: You should put that _before_ the rewriting WP does itself, before the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment.

Comment: @CBroe, I have tried, Added a second code at the top ,Cleared the cache, but still same issue

Comment: Cleared what cache, WP or browser? Browsers tend to cache 301 redirects really hard, so try in a private tab that doesn't have any history.

Comment: Yes, Cleared the browser cache and cleared WProcket cache but nothing is working

Comment: What happens when you disable WP Rocket completely?

Comment: @CBroe, I am getting the same issue. i have added the screenshot in the question at the end

Comment: Sorry, but I can't really make sense of this. You did not get redirected to the `www.` version here, so apparently your addition didn't do anything at all. But then the rest should still be working the same as it did before ... so if you did not also get a 404 for that same URL back then already, before you even tried to implement this www redirect, I really don't know what the explanation could be. My advice would be to enable some rewrite logging, so that you can retrace what happens exactly.

Comment: @CBroe, Do I need to change anything on DNS level? because my main domain is redirecting to www but not inner pages..

Comment: @CBroe, I have tried whatever you have suggested but nothing is working for me.. I have added one more image in the question at the end. If I access my URL with www then it's working but if I remove www then I am getting 404

Comment: Nah, DNS is not very likely to be the cause here - I would assume you already have both versions of the host name, with and without the `www.`, pointing to the same server IP address? Whether they both get routed into the same Virtual Host on the server, would be more interesting.